# Java XML Serialization not propagated to child objects

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I have these classes:

```
public class PartialScanDTO implements Serializable {

    String invoiceNumber;
    String seal;
    Integer truckNumber;
    List<ScanDetailDTO> scanDetails;

... // getters and setters

} 

public class ScanDetailDTO implements Serializable {

    String returnableType;
    String description;
    Integer expectedQuantity;
    List<ReturnableDTO> returnablesList;
    Boolean notInDBError;

.. // getters and setters
}

public class ReturnableDTO implements Serializable {

    String code;
    String typeCode;
    String description;
    Boolean isEditable;
    Boolean codeFormatError;
    .. // getters and setters
}
```

I'm using the following code to serialize `PartialScanDTO`:

```
public static void write(PartialScanDTO ps, String filename) throws Exception {
    XMLEncoder encoder =
            new XMLEncoder(
            new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(filename)));
    encoder.writeObject(ps);
    encoder.close();
}
```

No error or exception is thrown but the resulting file does not contain the XML for `ScanDetailDTO` nor `ReturnableDTO`. This is the XML generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<java version="1.6.0_26" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <object class="dto.PartialScanDTO"> 
  <void property="invoiceNumber"> 
   <string>55rrg</string> 
  </void> 
  <void property="seal"> 
   <string>123123 / 13213</string> 
  </void> 
  <void property="truckNumber"> 
   <int>666</int> 
  </void> 
 </object> 
</java>
```

As you can see, all my classes implement `Serializable` and all their properties are serializable, yet the resulting XML is incomplete.

Any ideas on how to get the complete XML?

Comment: Have you tried using a ScanDetailDTO[] instead of List<ScanDetailDTO>? I seem to remember somewhere that complex List  Objects produced un-wanted results.

Comment: Can you post the code where the `PartialScanDTO` object is filled out with data?

Comment: It works now. I changed `List` to `ArrayList` everywhere. I read somewhere that since `List` is only an interface it does not implement the `Serializable` interface but `ArrayList` does. Also, I had one getter/setter with the wrong name (after refactoring, netbeans only changes the field name but not the getter/setter name). I'm not in the mood of testing which one did the trick but I guess it is  `List` not implementing `Serializable` what causes the problem. I would expect that if some getter/setter has a wrong name, the result would be a missing field in the XML. Let me know what you think.